# Проверка выполнения серверных hook-ов

Tags: git, git-push, hook

Как проверить выполнение серверных hook-ов?
Проверила выполнение клиентского hook-а. Но не понимаю, как проверить выполнение серверного. 
Например, когда человек делает git push. post-update при этом должен срабатывать. Не понимаю, что написать в скрипте, чтобы увидеть, что post-update действительно выполнился.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ - вывести любое сообщение в любой файл логов.
Лучше конечно чтобы в сообщении содержалось текущее время и все входные параметры хука.

Comment: Пробовала так сделать. Но не поняла, где создаётся файл. :(

Comment: Задайте ему абсолютный путь ко временному каталогу. По умолчанию без пути это будет текущий каталог процесса. Если скрипт не меняет его, то процесса, вызвавшего скрипт.